# Convert array of strings to a single integer

Tags: arrays, database, optimization, permissions, roles

I am trying to create a "permissions" system where I can store all the permissions a user has. Currently, all the permissions of a user are stored as an array inside the database:

```
[
    'role.users.view',
    'role.users.manage',
    'role.users.delete'
    ...
]
```

However, the more permissions I create, the bigger the size of the database becomes. As a result, I would like to be able to store all this array as an unique string/integer/identifier which allows me to efficiently transform the array above into a single integer - let's say the array of strings above becomes the number `1290481294`. My initial thought would have been to construct an integer based on whether the permission is on/off - resulting in an integer like `10101010101` - but this number would also become ridiculously long; so I'm trying to find a more efficient approach to this.

I am completely sure there is already an existing technique for this, but I don't really know how it is called or where I can document myself upon the subject.

tl;dr: I am trying to convert the array of strings above into a single, as-short-as-possible integer.

Comment: Well, you could convert that "number" to decimal.
Or directly work with powers of 2.

Comment: Your initial guess is good, but you have to think in binary. See the answer below.
Can I know which coding language you're using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with Python you could use this.

```py
all_permissions = [ # List of all permissions (prefarably unique)
    'role.users.view',
    'role.users.manage',
    'role.users.delete',
    'role.message.view',
    'role.message.send',
    'role.message.delete'
]
permission_flag = 1
permission_flags = {}
permission_lookup = {}
for i, permission in enumerate(all_permissions): # Initiate flags
    permission_flags[permission] = permission_flag
    permission_lookup[i] = permission
    permission_flag *= 2
#all_permissions = [] # Clear all_permissions, we don't need it anymore

def function_a_1():
    # Permissions to permission_identifier
    permissions = [ # Old user permissions
        'role.users.view',
        'role.users.delete',
        'role.users.delete'
    ]
    permission_identifier = 0
    for permission in permissions:
        permission_identifier |= permission_flags[permission] # Bitwise or
    return permission_identifier

def function_b_1():
    # permission_identifier to Permissions
    permissions = []
    permission_identifier = 6
    for permission, permission_flag in permission_flags.items(): # Initiate flags
        if permission_identifier & permission_flag:
            permissions.append(permission)
    return permissions

def function_b_2():
    # permission_identifier to Permissions
    permissions = []
    permission_identifier = 6
    permission_index = 0
    while permission_identifier:
        if permission_identifier % 2:
            permissions.append(all_permissions[permission_index])
        permission_identifier //= 2
        permission_index += 1
    return permissions

print(function_a_1())
print(function_b_1())
print(function_b_2())
from timeit import repeat
loops = 1_000_000
count = 1
print(loops * min(repeat("function_b_1()", globals=globals(), repeat=loops, number=count)))
print(loops * min(repeat("function_b_2()", globals=globals(), repeat=loops, number=count)))
```

Ouput:

```
5
['role.users.manage', 'role.users.delete']
['role.users.manage', 'role.users.delete']
0.4998873919248581
0.3998866304755211
```

This is correct, because:

- 2^0 + 2^2 = 1 + 4 = 5
- 2^1 + 2^3 = 2 + 4 = 6

The last function might be better when users have few roles

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, I was trying to do this in typescript - but I've managed to successfully write its typescript alternative based on your solution. Thank you very much! Here's the code: https://shorturl.at/ahjHV

Comment: there's something I don't quite know how I could tackle - how can I do the inverse of lines 17-21 in the code I've linked above? I would like to take that number and verify if that number includes the role for 'role.users.manage', for example

Comment: You're link is dead, but I suspect you want to convert this back to a list..

Comment: Yes, I would like to convert it back to a list of roles - is that possible? I would greatly appreciate an example for that - doesn't matter what language it is in. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to check if this solution is fast enough...

Comment: @Radu, I've two solutions for you.

Comment: OK, can I get an upvote too?